# What should I do when "Package-Requires" are too long?

Tags: emacs, elisp

I am writing a package, and the package depends on a lot of packages.

I want every line to be within 80 chars length.

But "Package-Requires" in the header are too long.

How can I split that?

Comment: Use a foo-pkg.el file instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no way to split it in the comment, as package.el uses `lm-header` and not `lm-header-multiline`.

You can always make a multi-file package, though, and write your own `define-package` invocation.  This is more of a pain though.